# how can i call a java class in ruby

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i call a java class in ruby?

Answer (score 8):

If you use JRuby, you can

```
require 'java'
```

and then instantiate a Java class using eg

```
object = Java::package.package.ClassName.new
```

and then call methods using

```
object.method(parameter)
```

for more information, see [Scripting Java libraries with JRuby](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/scripting-java-libraries-with-jruby/)

Answer (score 1):

try this Java/Ruby Bridge:

[Link](http://rjb.rubyforge.org/)

The Bridge itselfs enables you to load java classes into your ruby Code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you wrap, or call, the Java class with another Java class with a `main()` method reading stdin or command-line arguments ? You can then spawn that as an executable from Ruby, write to stdin and read from stdout.

That may be the *simplest* answer, bearing in mind it's not the fastest mechanism, or in some cases the most practical. For some scenarios, however, it may be the most pragmatic.